# Error with overloading operator in string project [SOLVED]

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement my overloading operator for this string project I am working on but I keep getting these following errors when running my program:

> undefined reference to `cs_mystring::MyString::operator=(cs_mystring::MyString const&)'|
>
> undefined reference to `cs_mystring::MyString::MyString(cs_mystring::MyString const&)'|

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef MYSTRING_H
#define MYSTRING_H

#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>      // for toupper()
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace cs_mystring
{
    class MyString
    {

    public:

        static const int MAX_INPUT_SIZE = 127;

        int length() const;
        MyString();  // default constructor
        MyString(const char* inString); // parameterized constructor

        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const MyString& printMe);
        friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, MyString& readMe);
        void readline(std::istream& in, char delimeter); //another setter type function

        char operator[] (int index) const;
        char& operator [] (int index);

        friend bool operator < (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp);
        friend bool operator <= (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp);
        friend bool operator > (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp);
        friend bool operator >= (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp);
        friend bool operator == (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp);
        friend bool operator != (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp);
        MyString operator += (const MyString& rightOp);
        friend MyString operator + (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp);

        ~MyString();  // class destructor
        MyString operator=(const MyString& right);  // = operator used in client code
        MyString(const MyString& copyMe);  //copy constructor makes a deep copy

    private:

        char *str;
    };
}

#endif
```

My cpp file:

```
#include "mystring.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>  
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace cs_mystring
{


MyString::MyString()  // default constructor
{
    str = new char[1];
    strcpy(str, "");
}

MyString::MyString(const char* inString) // parameterized constructor
{
    str = new char[strlen(inString) + 1];
    strcpy(str, inString);
}

MyString::~MyString()
{
    delete [] str;
}

ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const MyString& printMe)
{
        out << printMe.str;
        return out;
}

istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, MyString& readMe)
{
        delete[] readMe.str;
        char tempString[MyString::MAX_INPUT_SIZE + 1];
        in >> tempString;
        readMe.str = new char[strlen(tempString) + 1];
        strcpy(readMe.str, tempString);
        return in;
}

void MyString::readline(std::istream& in, char delimeter)
{

        char tempStr[MyString::MAX_INPUT_SIZE + 1];
        in.getline(tempStr, MyString::MAX_INPUT_SIZE + 1, delimeter);
        delete [] str;
        str = new char[strlen(tempStr) + 1];
        strcpy(str, tempStr);
}

int MyString::length() const
{
    return strlen(str);
}

char MyString::operator[](int index)const
{
    assert(index >= 0 && index < strlen(str));
    return str[index];
}

char& MyString::operator[](int index)
{
    assert(index >= 0 && index < strlen(str));
    return str[index];
}

bool operator < (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp)
{
    return strcmp(leftOp.str, rightOp.str) < 0;
}

bool operator <= (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp)
{
    return strcmp(leftOp.str, rightOp.str) <= 0;
}

bool operator > (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp)
{
    return strcmp(leftOp.str, rightOp.str) > 0;
}

bool operator >= (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp)
{
    return strcmp(leftOp.str, rightOp.str) >= 0;
}

bool operator == (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp)
{
    return strcmp(leftOp.str, rightOp.str) == 0;
}

bool operator != (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp)
{
    return strcmp(leftOp.str, rightOp.str) != 0;
}

MyString operator + (const MyString& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp)
{
    MyString tempString;
    delete [] tempString.str;
    tempString.str = new char[strlen(leftOp.str) + strlen(rightOp.str) + 1];
    strcpy(tempString.str, leftOp.str);
    strcat(tempString.str, rightOp.str);

    return tempString;


}

MyString MyString::operator += (const MyString& rightOp)
{
    *this = *this + rightOp;

    return *this;
}

/*MyString MyString::operator=(const MyString& right)
{
    if (this != &right)
    {
    delete[] str;
    str = new char[strlen(right.str) + 1];
    strcpy(str, right.str);
    }

        return *this;
} */

}
```

my main file using everything in my class:

```
 #include "mystring.h"
 #include <fstream>
 #include <cctype>     
 #include <string>
 #include <cassert>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 using namespace cs_mystring;

void BasicTest();
void RelationTest();
void ConcatTest();
void CopyTest();
MyString AppendTest(const MyString& ref, MyString val);
string boolString(bool convertMe);

int main()
{
    cout << "Project#4: MyString class (ADT) client program to test CLASS INVARIANT\n";
    cout << "The class has one private data member defined as follows:\n";
    cout << "char *str;\n";
    cout << "str always represents a valid null-terminated c-string for each instance\n";
    cout << "of a MyString class object class.\n";
    cout << "The client code provides an interface to test correct operations on MyString\n";
    cout << "objects\n";

    cout << "\nHere is a list of tests and the order in which the tests will be conducted\n";
    cout << "1. BasicTest\n";
    cout << "2. RelationTest\n";
    cout << "3. ConcatTest\n";
    cout << "4. CopyTest\n\n";

    BasicTest();
    RelationTest();
    ConcatTest();
   /* CopyTest(); */

    cout << "\nProject#4 -MyString class (ADT) testing now concluded.\n";
    cout << "MyString class destructor has been invoked and memory from the heap deallocated\n";
    cout << "Check output for correct results from the MyString class (ADT) implementation.\n";


    return 0;
}


string boolString(bool convertMe) {
    if (convertMe) {
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
}


void BasicTest()
{
    MyString s;
    int stringLength;

    cout << "***********************************************************************\n";
    cout << "* Basic Test: Testing various member constructor options and nonmember*\n";
    cout << "* friend ostream << operator for basic MyString object creation &     *\n";
    cout << "* printing                                                            *\n";
    cout << "***********************************************************************\n";

    const MyString strs[] =
                {MyString("Wow"), MyString("C++ is neat!"),
                 MyString(""), MyString("a-z")};


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cout << "string [" << i <<"] = " << strs[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n***********************************************************************\n";
    cout << "* Basic Test: Testing nonmember friend istream >> and ostream <<      *\n";
    cout << "* operators for reading and display of MyString objects from data file*\n";
    cout << "***********************************************************************\n";

    cout << endl << "----- first, word by word" << endl;
    ifstream in("mystring_data.txt");
    assert(in);
    while (in.peek() == '#'){
        in.ignore(128, '\n');
    }
    in >> s;
    while (in) {
        cout << "Read string = " << s << endl;
        in >> s;
    }
    in.close();

    cout << "\n*************************************************************************\n";
    cout << "* Basic Test: Testing member function readline read, a nonmember friend *\n";
    cout << "* istream >> and ostream <<operators for reading and display of MyString*\n";
    cout << "* objects from data file                                                *\n";
    cout << "* ***********************************************************************\n";

    cout << endl << "----- now, line by line" << endl;
    ifstream in2("mystring_data.txt");
    assert(in2);
    while (in2.peek() == '#'){
        in2.ignore(128, '\n');
    }
    s.readline(in2, '\n');
    while (in2) {
        cout << "Read string = " << s << endl;
        s.readline(in2, '\n');
    }
    in2.close();

    cout << "\n****************************************************************************\n";
    cout << "* Basic Test: Testing access to characters (using const and non const)     *\n";
    cout << "* using constructors, member function length that returns a cstring length,*\n";
    cout << "* the square bracket [] overloaded operator and a nonmember friend         *\n";
    cout << "* istream >> for display of MyString objects content                       *\n";
    cout << "* **************************************************************************\n";

    cout << endl << "----- Testing access to characters (using const)" << endl;
    const MyString s1("abcdefghijklmnopqsrtuvwxyz");
    cout <<  "Whole string is " << s1 << endl;
    cout << "now char by char: ";
    stringLength = s1.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++){
        cout << s1[i];
    }


    cout << endl << "\n----- Testing access to characters (using non-const)" << endl;
    MyString s2("abcdefghijklmnopqsrtuvwxyz");
    cout <<  "Start with " << s2;
    stringLength = s2.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++){
        s2[i] = toupper(s2[i]);
    }
    cout << " and convert to " << s2 << endl;
}


void RelationTest()
{

    cout << "\n***********************************************************************\n";
    cout << "* RelationTest: Testing nonmember friend binary Boolean <, <=, >, >=, *\n";
    cout << "*  ==, != relational operators between MyString objects               *\n";
    cout << "***********************************************************************\n";

    const MyString strs[] =
        {MyString("app"), MyString("apple"), MyString(""),
        MyString("Banana"), MyString("Banana")};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << "Comparing " << strs[i] << " to " << strs[i+1] << endl;
        cout << "\tIs left < right? " << boolString(strs[i] < strs[i+1]) << endl;
        cout << "\tIs left <= right? " << boolString(strs[i] <= strs[i+1]) << endl;
        cout << "\tIs left > right? " << boolString(strs[i] > strs[i+1]) << endl;
        cout << "\tIs left >= right? " << boolString(strs[i] >= strs[i+1]) << endl;
        cout << "\tDoes left == right? " << boolString(strs[i] == strs[i+1]) << endl;
        cout << "\tDoes left != right ? " << boolString(strs[i] != strs[i+1]) << endl;
    }


    cout << "\n***********************************************************************\n";
    cout << "* RelationTest: Testing nonmember friend binary Boolean <, <=, >, >=, *\n";
    cout << "*  ==, != relational operators between MyString objects and char      *\n";
    cout << "***********************************************************************\n";

    MyString s("he");
    const char *t = "hello";
    cout << "Comparing " << s << " to " << t << endl;
    cout << "\tIs left < right? " << boolString(s < t) << endl;
    cout << "\tIs left <= right? " << boolString(s <= t) << endl;
    cout << "\tIs left > right? " << boolString(s > t) << endl;
    cout << "\tIs left >= right? " << boolString(s >= t) << endl;
    cout << "\tDoes left == right? " << boolString(s == t) << endl;
    cout << "\tDoes left != right ? " << boolString(s != t) << endl;

    MyString u("wackity");
    const char *v = "why";
    cout << "Comparing " << v << " to " << u << endl;
    cout << "\tIs left < right? " << boolString(v < u) << endl;
    cout << "\tIs left <= right? " << boolString(v <= u) << endl;
    cout << "\tIs left > right? " << boolString(v > u) << endl;
    cout << "\tIs left >= right? " << boolString(v >= u) << endl;
    cout << "\tDoes left == right? " << boolString(v == u) << endl;
    cout << "\tDoes left != right ? " << boolString(v != u) << endl;

}


void ConcatTest()
{
    cout << "\n************************************************************************\n";
    cout << "* ConcatTest: Testing nonmember friend binary arithmetic + operator    *\n";
    cout << "* that do concatenation on MyString objects                            *\n";
    cout << "************************************************************************\n";

    cout << "\n----- Testing concatenation on MyStrings\n";
    const MyString s[] =
            {MyString("outrageous"), MyString("milk"), MyString(""),
            MyString("cow"), MyString("bell")};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << s[i] << " + " << s[i+1] << " = " << s[i] + s[i+1] << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n************************************************************************\n";
    cout << "* ConcatTest: Testing nonmember friend binary arithmetic + operator    *\n";
    cout << "* that do concatenation between MyString objects and char*             *\n";
    cout << "************************************************************************\n";

    cout << "\n----- Testing concatenation between MyString and char *\n";
    const MyString a("abcde");
    const char *b = "XYZ";
    cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << a + b << endl;
    cout << b << " + " << a << " = " << b + a << endl;


    cout << "\n************************************************************************\n";
    cout << "* ConcatTest: Testing member binary arithmetic += operator             *\n";
    cout << "* that do concatenation between MyString objects and char*             *\n";


    cout << "\n----- Testing shorthand concat/assign using MyString and 
  char *\n";
    MyString u("I love ");
    const char *v = "programming";
    cout << u << " += " << v << " = ";
    cout << (u += v) << endl;
}
```

I can provide the rest of the code if needed

Comment: Do you have an assignment operator or copy constructor declared/defined anywhere? Also your `+=` operator should return a reference. As is you're returning a copy. Totally unnecessary.

Comment: Have you implemented the copy-constructor and copy-assignment?

Comment: Let me update the post with the following,

Comment: Post has been updated with my code so far, could it be me not defining my copy function and = function yet?

Comment: The definition of the copy assignment operator is commented out and as mentioned earlier, the signature should be `MyString& operator=(const MyString& right);`

Comment: Just defined that and another function and works as intended! Well that was a very dumb mistake on my part.